# How to configure Webpack to display images uploaded on-the-fly in a certain directory?

Tags: webpack, jhipster

My app is a JHipster app, which is shipped with Webpack.

I upload images via a java REST API, then they are put in a directory within the webapp (named "photos/").
To display them in the webapp, I send a JS object including the image url in the angular/JS script.
Also I want to be able to access them directly with their URL. I'd want also using a directory that would not be erased in future builds.

I can't manage to configure properly webpack : I get an html 404 error ( from inside the webapp, and by direct URL )
All the infos I can get for now concern static image displayed from inside the webapp, and I don't get how to adapt for my issue.

I've added this in webpack.common.js

```
         {
              test: /photos\/.*\.jpg$/i,
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[name].jpg',
                outputPath: 'photos/',
                publicPath: 'photos/'
            }
          },
```

Here's the HTML bit associated

```html
                <dd *ngFor="let path of observation.imagesPath" >
                    <div>
                        <a href="{{path}}">
                            <img class="t_imageGalery" src="{{path}}" />

                        </a>
                    </div>
                </dd>
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, it's my first app with webpack.

Comment: It's  not a work for webpack as your images do not exist when webpack bundles your app, your images should be served as-is from java backend.

Comment: yes, thank, actually I was  drafting my own reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reply myself just in case somebody have the same problem in the future.
After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889634/serve-images-dynamically-with-webpack), I undestood that the issue has nothing to do with webpack (which is not a webserver, obviously).

So I simply used the spring boot webMvcConfigrer by adding this code bit in WebConfigurer

```java
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/photos/**")
          .addResourceLocations("file:" + env.getProperty("storage.imagepath"));
     }
```

Comment: As a bonus, you could use a field annotated with `@Value("storage.imagepath")` or even define a URL in your application properties